# Android studio Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on project ':app'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to load an `APP`.  But I am getting an error

> Build file 'F:\Android Studio Projects\SalesManagement-Agent\app\build.gradle' line: 30

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on project ':app'.

**Gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
    }

allprojects {
  repositories {
     jcenter()
}}
```

**And**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.anik.agent"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10'
implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.6') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try build-tools `30.0.3` and make sure the Gradle plugin is rather current. Back then keyword `implementation` didn't exist and was called `compile` (which is deprecated and will be removed in Gradle 7).

Comment: Tried but same  result :|

Answer (score 0):

Please check the folder under "app", there needs a folder named "libs".
Suggest change your build-tool-version(ex: **29.0.3**) and gradle version(ex: **4.1.2**) too.

Comment: yes there is  a folder named `libs` what to do with it ?

Comment: The error message said you do not have this folder. I had test on my project, if I delete the app/libs will got same error message